# Read data from an excel sheet with javascript and fill an html form with that data

Tags: json

I want read an excel sheet with javascript and fill an html form with that data kindly help me please .

Comment: You have to be more specific. In what environment in the browser, serverside in nodejs and passing the data to the client, in an desktop app using electron, ... . And why do you tag the question only with `json` how is that related to `json`?

Comment: I am using browser at client side and i don't to use any database. I read some where that it is possible with json that why i mention json. Actually i have no experience in java script that's i need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sudo npm install excel-export

next create a get method where you want write excel export code and then copy bellow code in this method:



get('excel',function(req,res){
    var nodeExcel=require('excel-export');
    var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
    var conf={}
    conf.cols=[{
            caption:'Sl.',
            type:'number',
            width:3
        },
        {
            caption:'Job',
            type:'string',
            width:50
        },
        {
            caption:'Date',
            type:'string',
            width:15
        }
        ];
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        var query=connection.query("select * from todo where user_id="+req.session.id,function(err,rows){
            arr=[];
            for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                job=rows[i].job;
                a=[i+1,job,(dateFormat(rows[i].add_date*1000, "dd/mm/yyyy"))];
                arr.push(a);
                }
                conf.rows=arr;
    var result=nodeExcel.execute(conf);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/vnd.openxmlformates');
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+"todo.xlsx");
    res.end(result,'binary');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should not install non global modules using root user. Even for global ones a setup without the need of root should be prefered.